# mac El Capitan connect to server using smb failed

Tags: macos, smb

Mac OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.5) want to connect to a server to access some shared images. 
`Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server`, then input address

```
smb://172.16.X.X/
```

then next step enter username and password, then it hints

```
Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.
```

but all my colleague could connect it successfully, only myself cannot connect it.

The error message in `Console` is

```
6/16/16 21:14:24.000 kernel[0]: smb_ntstatus_error_to_errno: Couldn't map ntstatus (0xc000019c) to errno returning EIO
6/16/16 21:14:25.000 kernel[0]: smb_ntstatus_error_to_errno: Couldn't map ntstatus (0xc000019c) to errno returning EIO
6/16/16 21:14:26.000 kernel[0]: smb_ntstatus_error_to_errno: Couldn't map ntstatus (0xc000019c) to errno returning EIO
6/16/16 21:14:26.465 NetAuthSysAgent[1218]: checkForDfsReferral: mounting dfs url failed, syserr = Unknown error: -1073741412
6/16/16 21:14:26.465 NetAuthSysAgent[1218]: smb_mount: mount failed to 172.16.X.X/
smb:, syserr = Unknown error: -1073741412
```

I also tried to connect it in terminal

```
mount -t smbfs  '//172.16.X.X/' share
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Users/foo/share: Unknown error: -1073741412
```

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this problem? I have the same kind of issue

Comment: no, but very strange, I created a new account--foo, then switch to the new user, the function is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.

1. Open Keychain Access
2. From the Keychain Access menu, select Ticket Viewer
3. For me, I needed to use a different network account than I was logged into on my Mac, so I clicked Add Identity, and entered the username and password.
4. Also, in the main Keychain Access window, I searched for the server name I was connecting to, double clicked on it, and added the account and password info I wanted to connect with (I'm not sure if this step was necessary)

When I tried my SMB share again, I was able to get in.

Answer (score 1):

I've just resolved the same problem but in my case I was trying to connect to MS Azure smb share. I was getting the same error. My problem was resolved as soon as I added share name after the address.
So for me it won't show the list of shares but if I add the name of a share to the url, it works. Try:

smb://172.16.X.X/sharename

Also, check your port 445 is open on your computer and on router.

(I know it's a late answer, but may be it will help somebody else)

Comment: In my case I had an invalid share name.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work,

Using Microsoft Azure's file share service, they provide a command to connect to your file share via SMB. This is the an example of what they give you (for Mac):

`mount_smbfs -d 777 -f 777 //appstore2021test [ACCESS_KEY]==@appstore2021test.file.core.windows.net demo`

You'll need to change it to

`mount_smbfs -d 777 -f 777 //appstore2021test:[ACCESS_KEY]==@appstore2021test.file.core.windows.net/demo demo`

'demo' is the name of the directory